# Is there a way to correctly sort unicode strings in SQLite using Python?

Tags: python, sqlite, unicode

Is there a simple way to order rows with unicode data in SQLite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLite has a BYOS (Bring Your Own Sorter) policy.  See the FAQ for [more details](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q18).  They chose not to include (by default) any Unicode-aware sorting algorithm, to keep the SQLite library svelte and easy to statically link in.

However, you can [create a collator](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html), that sorts however you please, then tell SQLite to use it.  As the other poster hinted at, there are collators in the source tree that do this using [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).  However, you can also use your own, which makes sense if you're using a library like GLib that has its own Unicode-awareness.

Answer (score 2):

There is a library called [ICU](http://icu-project.org/) that can do proper unicode sorting for you; there's a good description in this other question:

[How to sort text in sqlite3 with specified locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611459/how-to-sort-text-in-sqlite3-with-specified-locale)