# Compiled version of Sqlite3 ICU Extension

Tags: sqlite, icu

I think sqlite3 very handy software on many situation. But I need ICU support for sort order. I red many documents at Internet. I gave up a few times to use sqlite, I deleted the my downloads. But I need sqlite again and again.
Is it so difficult to create an extension for download? Where can I find a ready to use extension?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Hi,
At http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611459/how-to-sort-text-in-sqlite3-with-specified-locale, klew explained what to do. But I don't have any environment to compile ICU. I need compiled an libSqliteIcu.so (called like that at that link).
Many many thanks for any help.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I provide compiled versions for Linux and macOS on my server: http://files.tempel.org/Various/Sqlite3ICUExtention

See also this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56148556/43615) with more details.