# Case insensitive utf8 select

Tags: php, sqlite, select, utf-8, case-sensitive

In SQLite I want to case-insensitive `"SELECT LIKE name"`
works fine for normal latin names, but when the name is in UTF-8 with non-latin characters then the select becomes case-sensitive, how to make it also case-insensitive like latin characters?

p.s. my sqlite is v3 and I connect with PHP PDO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For SQLite you have 2 options:

1. compile it with ICU support: [How to compile](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html), [Compilation options](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html)
2. override the LIKE function, here is a complete solution (from http://blog.amartynov.ru/?p=675)

```php
$pdo = new PDO("sqlite::memory:");

# BEGIN

function lexa_ci_utf8_like($mask, $value) {
    $mask = str_replace(
        array("%", "_"),
        array(".*?", "."),
        preg_quote($mask, "/")
    );
    $mask = "/^$mask$/ui";
    return preg_match($mask, $value);
}

$pdo->sqliteCreateFunction('like', "lexa_ci_utf8_like", 2);

# END

$pdo->exec("create table t1 (x)");
$pdo->exec("insert into t1 (x) values ('[Привет España Dvořák]')");

header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf8");
$q = $pdo->query("select x from t1 where x like '[_РИ%Ñ%ŘÁ_]'");
print $q->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: google does not like me asking how to compile with ICU, provide links please. Otherwise you are the first person to provide a proper answer!

Comment: @YuriKolovsky As for compiling ICU, there's no definitive guide and I haven't tried this way, so you still have to google :)

Comment: the provided example does not seem to work with Russian letters, `LIKE '%ОЛЬ%'`. What am I doing wrong? if I manage to solve this, you will be my new programming role model :)

Comment: @YuriKolovsky indeed, my function failed with Cyrillic chars. I updated the blog post - please check the new version and let me know if it works. Thank you for testing :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a [no-case collation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation), such as : `LIKE name COLLATE NOCASE`

If you need specific characters that are not part of ASCII to be compared with case folding, the `NOCASE` will not work, as such folding is not supported by SQLite - you will have to provide your own collation function using your Unicode library of choice and `sqlite3_create_collation()`.

**EDIT**: also, this might be interesting:

[How to sort text in sqlite3 with specified locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611459/how-to-sort-text-in-sqlite3-with-specified-locale)

Comment: According to the documentation for NOCASE it's only ASCII; it specifically says its excludes UTF-8.

Comment: What the documentation says is that UTF-8 characters **that are not part of ASCII** will be case-sensitive. So A = a but Œ != œ. Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

An improved version of `LIKE` overloading via a UDF:

```
$db->sqliteCreateFunction('like',
    function ($pattern, $data, $escape = null) use ($db)
    {
        static $modifiers = null;

        if (isset($modifiers) !== true)
        {
            $modifiers = ((strncmp($db->query('PRAGMA case_sensitive_like;')->fetchColumn(), '1', 1) === 0) ? '' : 'i') . 'suS';
        }

        if (isset($data) === true)
        {
            if (strpbrk($pattern = preg_quote($pattern, '~'), '%_') !== false)
            {
                $regex = array
                (
                    '~%+~S' => '.*',
                    '~_~S' => '.',
                );

                if (strlen($escape = preg_quote($escape, '~')) > 0)
                {
                    $regex = array
                    (
                        '~(?<!' . $escape . ')%+~S' => '.*',
                        '~(?<!' . $escape . ')_~S' => '.',
                        '~(?:' . preg_quote($escape, '~') . ')([%_])~S' => '$1',
                    );
                }

                $pattern = preg_replace(array_keys($regex), $regex, $pattern);
            }

            return (preg_match(sprintf('~^%s$~%s', $pattern, $modifiers), $data) > 0);
        }

        return false;
    }
);
```

Respects the [`case_sensitive_like` PRAGMA](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_case_sensitive_like) and correctly handles [`x LIKE y ESCAPE z` syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like).

I also wrote another version that does [basic](https://gist.github.com/alixaxel/7286763#file-sqlite-udf-like-icu-roman-php) and [extended romanization](https://gist.github.com/alixaxel/7286763#file-sqlite-udf-like-icu-roman-extended-php) of `x` and `y` values, so that an accented character will match it's unaccented counterpart, for instance: `SELECT 'Á' LIKE 'à%';`.

You can [star the gist](https://gist.github.com/alixaxel/7286763) to keep an eye on occasional updates.