# how to enable sqlite extension to support unicode in xampp?

Tags: php, sqlite, xampp

I heard that you need to enable `enable-sqlite-utf8`, but I could not find this line anywhere in xampp or the documentation, how to enable full utf8 support in pdo_sqlite extension in xampp (windows)?

But I guess that I'm wrong there and enable-sqlite-utf will not enable correct unicode LIKE operator with non ASCII characters, for it to work I think I need to enable ICU for sqlite in XAMPP, but how?

ie: I can't get #18 to work
http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q18

Comment: Isn't it enabled by default? Did you try using an sqlite db?

Comment: I don't think it is enabled, if it was, unicode chars should be case-insensitive in the LIKE operator that I'm using.

Comment: I noticed the comment "intl has the icu sqlite extension" in the php.ini file in xampp, where extension=php_intl.dll is enabled, I wonder how to actually have ICU work? googling for "xampp ICU" brings up this very same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

> The LIKE operator is case sensitive by default for unicode characters that are beyond the ASCII range. For example, the expression 'a' LIKE 'A' is TRUE but 'æ' LIKE 'Æ' is FALSE.)

You can however use the ICU extension for sqlite to get this functionality, see also [#611459](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611459/how-to-sort-text-in-sqlite3-with-specified-locale).

Comment: I know that, What I want to know is HOW to enable ICU for sqlite in xampp?

Comment: Look at the second answer of the question I linked to. And additional information here: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki/wiki?p=LoadableExtensions

Comment: Second answer suggests I compile with gcc (reading from other questions it's actually g++), also I'm on Windows and have no clue how to compile.

Comment: Another way to get the LIKE function to work is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285396/case-insensitive-utf8-select

Comment: @TimoHuovinen: Beware with that function as it won't be called if you use an escape character. Check my improved version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19749906/89771.