# How to compile sqlite with ICU?

Tags: c++, linux, sqlite

I downloaded sqlite from http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-autoconf-3070701.tar.gz

How can I compile sqlite with icu ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) You can compile it as dynamic extension of SQLite
Citing http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/fileview?f=sqlite/ext/icu/README.txt

> The easiest way to compile and use the ICU extension is to build
>     and use it as a dynamically loadable SQLite extension. To do this
>     using gcc on *nix:
>
> ```
> gcc -shared icu.c `icu-config  --cppflags --ldflags` -o libSqliteIcu.so
> ```
>
> You may need to add "-I" flags so that gcc can find sqlite3ext.h
>     and sqlite3.h. The resulting shared lib, libSqliteIcu.so, may be
>     loaded into sqlite in the same way as any other dynamically loadable
>     extension.

(loading is  `.load libSqliteIcu.so` in SQLite prompt)

2) You can compile SQLite with ICU enabled. According to http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html
 you should define macro `SQLITE_ENABLE_ICU`:

Add `-DSQLITE_ENABLE_ICU` to the CFLAGS variable or add `#define SQLITE_ENABLE_ICU` in some config file.

Okay, there is something here not described in standard documentation. Here is an example of calling configure with ICU enabled:

```
 CFLAGS='-O3 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_ICU' CPPFLAGS=`icu-config --cppflags` LDFLAGS=`icu-config --ldflags` ./configure
```

You also should have `icu-config` program installed (it is from  `libicu` or  `libicu-dev` package)

Comment: It will link dynamically if you have an dynamic libicu.so (you will). To change linkage to static, run `icu-config --ldflags` and check, if its output contains -Bstatic or -Bdynamic. If not, change LDFLAGS to `LDFLAGS="-Wl,-Bstatic "\`icu-config --ldflags\`" -Wl,-Bdynamic"`

Comment: I am getting sqlite3.c:(.text+0xcb64b): undefined reference to `utf8_nextCharSafeBody_3_6'

Comment: Don't forget to install ICU and SQLite3 development packages `sudo apt update && sudo apt install libicu-dev libsqlite3-dev -y`

Answer (score 3):

Whether you build the amalgamation with icu enabled or just icu extension depends on what you want to do with icu.

If you need an icu tokenizer (to do fts) you need to build amalgamation, if you just need the icu functions as https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/dir?ci=6cb537bdce85e088&name=ext/icu list then icu extension is enough.

When building icu extension I find I can not name it `libSqliteIcu.so` as that readme said b/c when I load it I got this error

```
sqlite> .load ./libSqliteIcu.so
Error: dlsym(0x7fa073e02c60, sqlite3_sqliteicu_init): symbol not found
```

After asking the question at [sqlit mail list](http://%20https://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@mailinglists.sqlite.org/msg112359.html)  I was told that, which I have confirm.

The symbol name is sqlite3_icu_init.  When you load module `lib<x>.so` the symbol `sqlite3_<x>_init` is called.  You need to either (a) rename the shared library to the correct name (`libicu.so`) or pass the name of the init function (sqlite3_icu_init) to the loader when you load the module, or (b) change the name of the `sqlite3_icu_init` function in the `icu.c` source so that it matches the name that the module loader is looking for ...

Answer (score 0):

To compile SQLite with ICU enabled, you should define macro `SQLITE_ENABLE_ICU`.

Make sure that you have `libicu-dev` (on Debian/Ubuntu) installed.

As @osgx wrote, the standard documentation is lacking ICU-specific flags that you also need to set. `icu-config` is deprecated and is missing on Ubuntu 20.04 onwards, thus you should use `pkg-config` instead:

```sh
CFLAGS="-O2 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_ICU `pkg-config --libs --cflags icu-uc icu-io`" ./configure
make
```

See:

- [How To Use ICU - C++ Makefiles](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu/howtouseicu.html#c-makefiles)
- [Compile-time Options of SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html)

Comment: everything looks fine when doing these step, but still got an error : `Error: unknown tokenizer: icu`  while create a virtual table  using tokenize=icu..

Comment: on android continue to have this error:
...sqlite3.c:213388:10: fatal error: 'unicode/uregex.h' file not found

#include <unicode/uregex.h>

         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~