# How to ignore accent in SQLite query (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, diacritics

I am new in Android and I'm working on a query in SQLite. 
My problem is that when I use accent in strings e.g.

- ÁÁÁ
- ááá
- ÀÀÀ
- ààà
- aaa
- AAA

If I do:

```
SELECT * FROM TB_MOVIE WHERE MOVIE_NAME LIKE '%a%' ORDER BY MOVIE_NAME;
```

It's return:

- AAA
- aaa (It's ignoring the others)

But if I do:

```
SELECT * FROM TB_MOVIE WHERE MOVIE_NAME LIKE '%à%' ORDER BY MOVIE_NAME;
```

It's return:

- ààà (ignoring the title "ÀÀÀ")

I want to select strings in a SQLite DB without caring for the accents and the case. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accented Search in sqlite (android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083446/accented-search-in-sqlite-android)

Comment: Not duplicate to the above - it is about correctly collating accented characters (upper/lowercase matching), not ignoring them.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Generally, string comparisons in SQL are controlled by column or expression `COLLATE` rules. In Android, only three collation sequences are [pre-defined](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html): BINARY (default), LOCALIZED and UNICODE. None of them is ideal for your use case, and the C API for installing new collation functions is unfortunately not exposed in the Java API.

To work around this:

1. Add another column to your table, for example `MOVIE_NAME_ASCII`
2. Store values into this column with the accent marks removed. You can remove accents by normalizing your strings to Unicode Normal Form D (NFD) and removing non-ASCII code points since NFD represents accented characters roughly as plain ASCII + combining accent markers:

   ```
   String asciiName = Normalizer.normalize(unicodeName, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
       .replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
   ```
3. Do your text searches on this ASCII-normalized column but display data from the original unicode column.

Comment: Works for me as well, but Im wondering if there's no others way to do that

Comment: I wonder... is there any alternative way? I already did a "normalized" column solution, but for small, 1To1 strings. However, for One2Many Strings this solution might be overkill!! SQL can declare and use functions, right? Also, I am using RoomDB. Isn't there some helper in RoomDB for these things? I wonder...

Answer (score 9):

In Android sqlite, `LIKE` and `GLOB` ignore both `COLLATE LOCALIZED` and `COLLATE UNICODE` (they only work for `ORDER BY`). However, there is a solution without having to add extra columns to your table. As @asat explains in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53535409/6766261), you can use `GLOB` with a pattern that will replace each letter with all the available alternatives of that letter. In Java:

```
public static String addTildeOptions(String searchText) {
    return searchText.toLowerCase()
                     .replaceAll("[aáàäâã]", "\\[aáàäâã\\]")
                     .replaceAll("[eéèëê]", "\\[eéèëê\\]")
                     .replaceAll("[iíìî]", "\\[iíìî\\]")
                     .replaceAll("[oóòöôõ]", "\\[oóòöôõ\\]")
                     .replaceAll("[uúùüû]", "\\[uúùüû\\]")
                     .replace("*", "[*]")
                     .replace("?", "[?]");
}
```

And then (not literally like this, of course):

```
SELECT * from table WHERE lower(column) GLOB "*addTildeOptions(searchText)*"
```

This way, for example in Spanish, a user searching for either *mas* or *más* will get the search converted into *m[aáàäâã]s*, returning both results.

It is important to notice that `GLOB` ignores `COLLATE NOCASE`, that's why I converted everything to lower case both in the function and in the query. Notice also that the `lower()` function in sqlite doesn't work on non-ASCII characters - but again those are probably the ones that you are already replacing!

The function also replaces both `GLOB` wildcards, `*` and `?`, with "escaped" versions.

Comment: I had to fix your regex to get it working, because it is inverted. Where is `.replaceAll("[aáàäâã]", "\\[aáàäâã\\]")` I had to use `.replaceAll("\\.*[aáàäâã]\\.*", "[aáàäâã]")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android NDK to recompile the SQLite source including the desired ICU (International Components for Unicode).
Explained in russian here:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/122408/

The process of compiling the SQLilte with source with ICU explained here:

[How to compile sqlite with ICU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578600/how-to-compile-sqlite-with-icu)

Unfortunately you will end up with different APKs for different CPUs.

Answer (score -2):

You need to look at these, not as accented characters, but as entirely different characters.  You might as well be looking for a, b, or c.  That being said, I would try using a regex for it.  It would look something like:

```
SELECT * from TB_MOVIE WHERE MOVIE_NAME REGEXP '.*[aAàÀ].*' ORDER BY MOVIE_NAME;
```