# android sqlite select like national characters independend

Tags: android, sqlite, select

I'm working on SELECT LIKE statement. How to make searching not dependend on national characters?

If I have pattern "theatre" the system should find columns containing "Theatre", "theatre" (thats easy ex. using "lower") but also "théâtre". Moreover I don't want to keep any own characters encoding table as I want to make my app to work with different languages.

And it should work in the opposite way, for "théâtre" as pattern, "Theatre", "theatre" and  "théâtre" should be found.

Any solution?

Comment: that requires a *collation*. not supported in sqlite3 on android.

Comment: One approach in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282083/how-to-ignore-accent-in-sqlite-query-android/16283863#16283863

Comment: @laalto - thank a lot, that's some kind of workaround but then database is definitely much bigger. Have you heard about any plans of adding new collate rules to Android sqlite3?

Comment: I was wondering if it's possible to do it in the opposite way. To keep data in the database as it is but to automatically  modify pattern to add those accented characters. Ex. when typing e some java bult function add eééęë etc. and then the same in captials. Have you ever heard about function like that?