# How to sort accented letters to be displayed in list view

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, utf-8

how do I sort the retrieved data from the database to be displayed as the testing data listed below if there are special characters as the Ã character?

1. Apple
2. ÃTest
3. Ãbc

---

Currently this is what I have

query(mDBOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
              columnList,selection,selectionArgs, null,  null, TestDBOpenHelper.COLUMN1)

When I tested the it on my device, it will display those below after the alphabet Z.

1. ÃTest
2. Ãbc

Could someone please teach me how do I fix this? thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As i know, you won't be able to work with such characters in SQLite as UNICODE,BINARY and LOCAlIZED are the only collation ways to use in sorting. but you can make a work around this. refer to this [How to ignore accent in SQLite query (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282083/how-to-ignore-accent-in-sqlite-query-android)

Comment: I had tried putting this COLLATE NOCASE into the order by , but still it doesn't seem to work T^T

Comment: Collate won't make it work as it will use the default collation in this case which is BINARY collation. you have to handle it your own way. check the link i posted, i think it's a good work around