# SQLite upper and lower case accentuation with LIKE statement

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've this 4 contacts stored in my android contacts list, it's a SQLite database.

```
António Meireles
AntÓnio Pinto
Ágata Silva
ágata Pereira
```

If I execute:

```
select _id, display_name from raw_contacts where upper(display_name) like upper('%antó%')
```

I get `António Meireles` and not both Antónios.

If I execute:

```
select _id, display_name from raw_contacts where upper(display_name) like upper('%á%')
```

I get `ágata Pereira` and not both Ágatas.

What is wrong here? Shouldn't the `upper()` function make it exactly the same on both sides and return both `António`s and `Ágata`s?

This is happening to me when I try to make my search case insensitive when accents come into equation. From what I read around it is advised to put both (comparator and string to be compared with) either uppercase or lowercase and both strings would match, but that's not happening in my case.

Comment: If you can influence the database schema and data going into it, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282083/how-to-ignore-accent-in-sqlite-query-android/16283863#16283863

Comment: @laalto I've seen that example before but unfortunately I can't apply it to my case as I'm dealing directly with Android's contact storage database. It's not my own database.

Comment: Yes I suspected that would be the case and didn't flag as duplicate. I don't know an answer off the bat and don't have the time to experiment right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html), about LIKE clause:

> Any other character matches itself or its lower/upper case equivalent
>   (i.e. case-insensitive matching).

But there is a bug annotation out there:

> SQLite only understands upper/lower case for ASCII characters by
>   default. The LIKE operator is case sensitive by default for unicode
>   characters that are beyond the ASCII range. For example, the
>   expression 'a' LIKE 'A' is TRUE but 'æ' LIKE 'Æ' is FALSE

So probably you have to omit the **upper** clauses and handle upper case for non ASCII characters by adding **or** case in the **where** clause.

i.e.

```
select _id, display_name from raw_contacts 
where 
    ((display_name like '%antó%') or
    (display_name like '%antÓ%'))
```