# SQLite - Queries with non-English characters don't show any results

Tags: android, sqlite, searchview

I'm using a SearchView widget and it works well, except for the fact the if the string I enter contains any non-English character the result is empty, even if it is clear that there ARE results

Example:

[image]

In the image shown above there are two results for the string **"chu"** but if I type **"ñ"** the ListView won't show any results and it's obvious that there are results.

This is what I've tried so far

```
public Cursor searchProductByDescription(String description) {
        String where = PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION + " LIKE LOWER( ? ) ";
        String[] whereArgs = { "%" + description + "%" };   

        this.openReadableDB();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(PRODUCT_TABLE, null, where, whereArgs, null,
                null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        this.closeDB();
        return cursor;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is an issue related to the searchview widget or to SQLite.
I've seen a couple of question in which they suggest converting the string to LOWER o UPPER case, but this solution didn't work for me.

I'd really appreciate if you could help me here.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LOWER()` only knows how to lowercase ASCII characters. `LIKE` is also case insensitive only with ASCII characters. And `ñ` is not an ASCII character.

For a solution, consider the following:

- Add another column to your table that you use for searches and use the original column only for display purposes.
- Store data in this column in a normalized form such as NFC and with the case converted consistently to upper/lowercase. For example:

  ```
  String stringToStore = Normalizer.normalize(originalString.toLowerCase(), Normalizer.Form.NFC);
  ```
- Normalize your search strings similarly in code.

If you want to ignore accent e.g. have `n` also match `ñ`, use a [slightly different approach to remove the accents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282083/how-to-ignore-accent-in-sqlite-query-android/16283863#16283863).