# SQLite 3: Character Issue While Ordering By Records

Tags: sqlite, collation

In my SQLite 3 Database, I have some records with Turkish characters such as "Ö", "Ü", "İ" etc. When I select my values with `SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME` query, the records that begin with these characters are coming at the end.

Normally, they should've come after the letter that is dot-less version of each. Like "Ö" is after "O", "Ü" is after "U".

Is it something about regional settings? Is there a way to control these settings?

I use SQLite Manager in Firefox to manage my DB.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I know it's not a solution for SQLite but for those who need to use SQLite DB in Objective-C, they can sort the data array after getting from SQLite DB. Here's a good solution: [How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)

Comment: I haven't done any of this with SQLite but maybe this will help: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation

Comment: I'll take a look and return here if it does. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You can enable the [SQLite "ICU" extension](https://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact?ci=trunk&filename=ext/icu/README.txt) to have correct sorting with accented characters. [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58901967/111036) details how to do it on a Debian-based system.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it seems there's no direct solution for this. For iOS at least. But there are ways to follow.

After I subscribed to mailing list of SQLite, user Named Jean-Christophe Deschamps came with this reply:

> "In my SQLite 3 Database, I have some records with Turkish characters
>   such as "Ö", "Ü", "İ" etc. When I select my values with 'SELECT * FROM
>   TABLE ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME' query, the records that begin with these
>   characters are coming at the end."
>
> Bare bone SQLite only collates correctly on the lower ASCII charset.
>   While that's fine for plain english, it doesn't work for most of us.
>
> "Normally, they should've come after the letter that is dot-less
>   version of each. Like "Ö" is after "O", "Ü" is after "U". Is it
>   something about regional settings? Is there a way to control these
>   settings?"
>
> You have the choice among some ways to get it right or close to right
>   for your language(s):
>
> o) use ICU either as an extension (for third-party managers) or
>   linked to
>       your application.
>       Advantages: it works 100% correctly for a given language at a time in each
>                   operation.
>       Drawbacks: it's huge and slow and it requires you register a collation for
>       every language you deal with. Also it won't work well for columns
>       containing several non-english languages.
>
> o) write your own collation(s) invoking your OS' ICU routines to
>   collate
>       strings.
>       Advantages: doesn't bloat your code with huge libraries.
>       Drawbacks: requires you write this extension (in C or something), same
>                   other drawbacks as ICU.
>
> o) If you use Windows, download and use the functions in the
>   extension I
>       wrote for a close-to-correct result.
>       Advantages: it's small, fairly fast and ready to use, it is language-
>                   independant yet works decently well for many languages at
>                   the same time; it also offers a number of Unicode-aware
>                   string manipulation functions (unaccenting or not) functions,
>                   a fuzzy search function and much more. Comes as a C source and
>                   x86 DLL, free for any purpose.
>       Drawback: it probably doesn't work 100% correctly for any language using
>                 more than "vanilla english letters": your dotless i will collate
>                 along dotted i, for instance. It's a good compromise between
>                 absolute correctness for ONE language and "fair" correctness for
>                 most languages (including some asian languages using diacritics)
>       Download: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26433628/unifuzz.zip
>
> "I use SQLite Manager in Firefox to manage my DB."
>
> My little extension will work with this one. You might also want to
>   try SQLite Expert which has ICU built-in (at least in its Pro version)
>   and *much* more.

Comment: thanks for answer! The Dropbox link above does not work anymore though.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the regional settings but first I would verify UTF-8 encoding is being used.

Comment: Thanks; I did verify, it is UTF-8.