# What is the Equivalent of Windows' CompareString function?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm having some trouble about ordering records in an SQLite table used for my iOS project.

I've been looking for solution for a while, also [asked the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813069/sqlite-3-character-issue-while-ordering-by-records).

Since then, I got some help from a user in SQLite mail-list and he suggested me an extension, but it's for windows. [Here is the link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26433628/unifuzz.zip).

And this extension is using CompareString function([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

So that if I can manage to find equivalent of this function in Mac, I might be able to use the library in my Xcode project. Furthermore, that could create an alternative SQLite extension for iOS developers.

So is there such a function in Mac OS? Mostly similar maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your question was down-voted by someone else... maybe it's because what you are asking for is not clear?

As for CompareString function equivalents, look at the various compare methods in NSString (such as `[NSString compare:]`) and see if you can use something like to sort your UITableView.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/compare:options:

Comment: That's acceptable but why not to mention the reason? Next time I'll try to be more clear then. Thank you, that seems to be a good point to start.

Comment: I'm still getting to know StackOverflow myself, but I believe the general purpose of voting on questions is to vote up a really good question or vote down a question that isn't very good. Also, if you accept an answer, you should mark the answer as "checked" (or accepted). It helps to motivate people to participate and help here.  :-)

Comment: I was just looking into the page, of course I'd mark it :-) Thanks, if there's an answer, it can't be anywhere else.