# SQLite and Turkish sorting/ordering

Tags: sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQLite 3: Character Issue While Ordering By Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813069/sqlite-3-character-issue-while-ordering-by-records)

The default SQLite configuration does not support Turkish ordering.

What can I do in SQLite to order/sort according to the Turkish alphabet?

Comment: I reckon the only two ways are: a.) modify the source of SQLite (and preferably contribute back your change) or b.) do the sorting in code after retrieving the data. b.) is admittedly suboptimal.

Comment: [similar question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813069/sqlite-3-character-issue-while-ordering-by-records

Comment: I have compiled  SQLite for iOS with the required parameters to support Turkish. It worked fine but it does add 200 mb additional size to the app.

Answer (score 1):

ISTM the only two strategies a 1) teaching SQLite about Turkish ordering or 2) using an external tool that already knows.

For 1) you would need to build a table with the characterset in the proper collation order and use it to drive a correct sort.  See section 6 Collation Sequences at http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html and the instructions for building a custom collation function: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html .  A custom collation function would do lookups into your ordered character table to determine which of two strings precedes the other.

For 2) just dump a CSV file and handoff the work to Python or somesuch.