# Sqlite order by special characters

Tags: android, objective-c, sqlite

I executed an SQLite query, but I got a result that is not in the order that we need,the character "á" is being shown after z.

How can I configure my query to ignore special characters?

Comment: see that it is not 'a', it is something like ' "á" '

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611459/how-to-sort-text-in-sqlite3-with-specified-locale

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you just want to ignore all the results having these special characters or you have difficulties in sorting the result.

You can treat this as a hint (not an answer):

```
SELECT * 
FROM _table-name_ 
WHERE _column-name_ COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN NOT LIKE '%[^ a-zA-Z]%'
```