# SQLite ORDER BY gives wrong order with language specific text (C#)

Tags: c#, sqlite, sql-order-by

I have an SQLite database, that contains many data.
I would like to get data with ORDER BY, that contains english letters and Á, É, Í, etc.
I'm using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` ORDER BY `columnname`;
```

It gives a wrong order: A-Z, Á, É, Í, etc.
But, the correct order: A, Á, B-E, É, F-I, Í, etc.

I'm using this query through a C# application.

Thanks for help:
Horbert

P.S.: It's Hungarian language, but it could be anything else.

Comment: I don't know.
It's the default, what is created by C# and SQLite dll.
Where can I see about?

Comment: You can add the collation in your order by:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms184391.aspx, http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms174596%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: I tried collateion whit this: UFT8, UTF8CI, UTF8_general_ci
It had written: no such collation sequence: ...

Comment: @FabriceMainguené This is SQLite. The collating methods are different

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that. Look this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611459/how-to-sort-text-in-sqlite3-with-specified-locale, I think it's the same problem than you