# How to make sqlite use unicode equivalence for queries

Tags: unicode, sqlite, normalization, unicode-normalization

Sqlite seems to compare unicode strings by code point instead of using unicode equivalence.  I need sqlite to use canonical unicode equivalence.  Is there a way to do this?

I am using sqlite 3.7.13

Comment: Which equivalence are you referring to? Canonical, compatibility, or something else?

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela: Canonical equivalence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to define your own collating sequence, either by [writing your own](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html), or by using the [ICU extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611459/how-to-sort-text-in-sqlite3-with-specified-locale).