# SQLite ordering column with accented characters

Tags: sqlite

I'm developping a website using **SQLite** databases with PHP. I'm running **Windows** (dev) and my production environment should be a ***nix platform**. Here is the schema of my table :

```
CREATE TABLE [animals](
    [id] INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    [name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

I want to **sort the `animals` by `name`** (contains accented characters). My SQL query is:

```
SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY name DESC
```

and I get :

```
éléphant
tigre
renard
chien
```

instead of,

```
tigre
renard
éléphant
chien
```

I've searched on the web. I tried,

```
SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY name COLLATE *binary|nocase|rtrim* DESC
```

but I have the same problem. I also tried,

```
SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY name COLLATE *localized|unicode* DESC
```

But I get an error (either my SQLite client crashes, either PHP returns the following error: `no such collation sequence: UNICODE`).

It seems there's a solution for Android, but I'm running Windows and my production environment should be a *nix platform.

How can I get my animals sorted the right way?

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58901967/111036) for how to enable the [SQLite "ICU" extension](https://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact?ci=trunk&filename=ext/icu/README.txt) to have correct sorting with accented characters. It is for a Debian-based system, but can easily be adapted for Windows I guess, by changing the `libicu.so` name to `libicu.dll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, SQLite has only ASCII collations.

It would be possible to use the ICU extension to get Unicode support, but PHP did not enable this.

But you can [create your own collation](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.createcollation.php) and implement the comparison in PHP.

Comment: is there a way to use ICU binary as SQLite extension? I'm currently trying to use Windows DLLs from the package icu4c-58_2-Win64-MSVC2015.zip, but without success... an help?